# How to change MacBook jack only input instead of input and output

Tags: macbook-pro, microphone

I have a lavalier microphone with 3 pins that I connected to my MacBook. When I connect the microphone to my MacBook, the MacBook thinks the microphone is "headphones with built in external mic". Does anyone know how to make the microphone only input?

Image:
[image]

Comment: Is it a balanced line mic? Computers tend not to be able to handle them (inc Macs) They expect it to be either unbalanced, or as you’ve discovered, a headset. They have no circuitry to unbalance the signal.

Comment: https://amzn.to/2BFuC61 is the link to the microphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question. You need to use an adapter to perform this task: Ultimate Lavalier Microphone for Bloggers and Vloggers Lapel Mic Clip-on Omnidirectional Condenser [on amazon](https://amzn.to/2BFuC61).

Comment: umm.. that's amazon home page only..